# Сфера употребления текста репортажа

Tags: употребление-слов

Сфера употребления текста репортажа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Репортаж - жанр журналистики, сфера употребления - печать, радио и телевидение.

РЕПОРТА́Ж, а, м. [фр. reportage < англ. to report сообщать].1.Сообщение о местных событиях, о событиях дня, информация (в печати, по радио, телевидению).Спортивный р. Р. с места событий.2.Репортерская работа.Мастер репортажа.Репорта́жный —относящийся к репортажу (в 1-м и 2-м знач.).
Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2008

Comment: Спасибо огромное!